# Sending data from RabbitMQ to Node.JS via Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, socket.io, rabbitmq

I am going to design a system where there is a two-way communication between clients and a web application. The web application can receive data from the client so it can persist it to a DB and so forth, while it can also send instructions to the client. For this reason, I am going to use Node.JS and Socket.IO.

I also need to use RabbitMQ since I want that if the web application sends an instruction to a client, and the client is down (hence the socket has dropped), I want it to be queued so it can be sent whenever the client connects again and creates a new socket.

From the client to the web application it should be pretty straightforward, since the client uses the socket to send the data to the Node.JS app, which in turn sends it to the queue so it can ultimately be forwarded to the web application. From this direction, if the socket is down, there is no internet connection, and hence the data is not sent in the first place, or is cached on the client.

My concern lies with the other direction, and I would like an answer before I design it this way and actually implement it, so I can avoid hitting any brick walls. Let's say that the web application tries to send an instruction to the client. If the socket is available, the web app forwards the instruction to the queue, which in turn forwards it to the Node.JS app, which in turn uses the socket to forward it to the client. So far so good. If on the other hand, the internet connection from the client has dropped, and hence the socket is currently down, the web app will still send the instruction to the queue. My question is, when the queue forwards the instruction to Node.JS, and Node.JS figures out that the socket does not exist, and hence cannot send the instruction, will the queue receive a reply from Node.JS that it could not forward the data, and hence that it should remain in the queue? If that is the case, it would be perfect. When the client manages to connect to the internet, it will perform a handshake once again, the queue will once again try to send to Node.JS, only this time Node.JS manages to send the instruction to the client.

Is this the correct reasoning of how those components would interact together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this won't work the way you want it to.

when the node process receives the message from rabbitmq and sees the socket is gone, you can easily `nack` the message back to the queue.

however, that message will be processed again immediately. it won't sit there doing nothing. the node process will just pick it up again. you'll end up with your node / rabbitmq thrashing as it just nacks a message over and over and over and over, waiting for the socket to come back online.

if you have dozens or hundreds of messages for a client that isn't connected, you'll have dozens or hundreds of messages thrashing round in circles like this. it will destroy the performance of both your node process and rabbitmq.

my recommendation:

when the node app receives the message from rabbitmq, and the socket is not available to the client, put the message in a database table and mark it as waiting for that client.

when the client re-connects, check the database for any pending messages and forward them all at that point.